for Windows 11, How to run PowerShell script and Keep PowerShell Console Open After Script Execution?
I need help with running a PowerShell script from Windows 11 desktop. After right click on ps1 file, I right click and select Run with PowerShell, the script still exit and I do not have time to view its content.
My steps as follows

I modified the registry as follows  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\powershell.exe\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" - 
NoExit \"& \\\"%1\\\"\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell&#92;&#48;\Command]
@="\"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" - 
NoExit \"-Command\" \"if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & \\\"%1\\\"\""


my powershell script is on "C:\Users\UserName\OneDrive\Desktop\findlatestfile.ps1" and is as follows

$directoryPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\UserName\"
$newestFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $directoryPath -File -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$newestFile.FullName
    
# Keep the console open
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

How to Keep PowerShell Console Open After Script Execution
